# What delimiter to use with keywords?

Tags: lightroom, metadata

I'm going through all my photos and one thing I'm doing is adding keywords so I don't need the file name to describe the photo.

I don't understand if they should be structured in any sort of way. I was simply typing in a few, like, "china taishan".

When I click to add one from the suggestion box, Lightroom adds a comma. So, if I click the suggestions for the next photo it will say "china, taishan". It appears to know the comma isn't a keyword.

Is there a convention I should use? I want to maintain a platform-agnostic approach so that my photos are easily transferable to other software in the future.

*Update*: I discovered that Lightroom was treating "china taishan" as a single keyword but I didn't know this because it truncates the suggestion to make it appear like a single word. Removed related wording from the post.

Comment: I have avoided keywords up to now, exactly because I am unclear on what their effects are and how much they are interchangeable. Looking forward to the answers!

Comment: Have you read [the helpx.adobe.com article "How to use keywords in Lightroom?"](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/keywords.html)  I'm having a problem distinguishing what it is you're actually asking other than general help on how to use keywords. Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Helpful link for Lightroom (thanks!), but more as a future reference. The main question from my post is "Is there a convention I should use?" As stated, I'd like to avoid Lightroom-specific functionality.

Comment: I'm not a photographer, or in the business at all. I would imagine that the business has best practices or a common pattern for keywording. Do people separate keywords with spaces? Or Dashes? Commas? Or does it not matter at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comma is probably the most common delimiter. Lightroom recognizes it by default. It can also treat a period (.) or slash (/) the same way but this is optional which suggests that it is less standard.

A space is not usually a delimiter since people can use names such as 'John Smith' as keywords. Do not use a vertical bar (|) either since that is usually considered a hierarchy separator.

Speaking of which, you can structure keyword as a hierarchy which shows as a tree in Lightroom but is flattened when Metadata is exported. For example, I have locations as [continent]|[country]|[city], so for example, *asia|thailand|bangkok*. In Lightroom it looks like a neatly organized tree:

```
asia
|-> thailand
    |->  bangkok
```

That makes it easy to find photos of Asia, Thailand or Bangkok without having to explicitly add all three keywords. When adding *bangkok*, Lightroom automatically knows what the parent keywords are.

Comment: are there any or operator? for example, you used asia thaiand tree... mine would be: asia or middle east -> X or Y -> ... even city name typo changed so there are lot of options...